# Invoke 'Rate My Computer' performance process

Tags: windows-7, deployment, windows-embedded-7

I am creating a re-deployable Windows 7 Embedded WIM image. In audit mode I have configured it to be as I want and run the sysprep process to generalise the image before capturing it.

All this works fine.

As part of the post deployment steps I have to ask the deployment engineer to run the 'Rate My Computer' tool manually from Control Panel -> Performance Information and Tools.

Ideally, I would prefer that my post deployment application (c#) takes care of this post driver installation.

Is there a way to invoke this process via command line / direct executable run ? I have been unable to find any reference to this outside of manually clicking to button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rate My Computer page can be launched like this:

```
C:\Windows\explorer.exe shell:::{78F3955E-3B90-4184-BD14-5397C15F1EFC}
```

You will still need manual interaction to start the  calculation.
As far as I know that just opens the application, you can't make it start automatically.

WINSAT is a command-line utility makes the same calculations. What I'm not sure about (don't have a Win7 system to test here) is if it will update the rating as shown in the Windows GUI.

```
winsat -?  for options (should be the "formal" parameter you are looking for.)
```

Please note that for both cases the user that runs this must be member of the Administrators group and in case of WINSAT the command-prompt (or your post-deployment applications if that calls it) must be run in "Run as Administrator" mode.